# Why Does Using A Convenience Initializer Fix My Issue?

Tags: swift, mapkit

Please have a look at the two versions of the Renderer class. Renderer1's initializer executes successfully. Renderer2's initializer crashes on the call to super.init. The init(overlay:) initializer referenced in the crash message is declared by MKOverlayRenderer which is 3 levels up the class hierarchy.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class Renderer1 : MKPolylineRenderer {

         convenience init(polyline: MKPolyline, lineWidth: CGFloat) {
             self.init(polyline: polyline)
             self.lineWidth = lineWidth
         }
    }

    class Renderer2 : MKPolylineRenderer {

        // Crash Message:
        // /Users/Robert/Temp/Test/Test/ViewController.swift: 22: 11: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(overlay:)' for class 'Test.Renderer2'
        // 2017-10-06 08:37:10.582531-0400 Test[2962:932545] /Users/Robert/Temp/Test/Test/ViewController.swift: 22: 11: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(overlay:)' for class 'Test.Renderer2'

        init(polyline: MKPolyline, lineWidth: CGFloat) {
            super.init(polyline: polyline) // <= Crashes Here!
            self.lineWidth = lineWidth
        }
    }

    private var renderer1: Renderer1? = nil
    private var renderer2: Renderer2? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        for latitude in 1 ... 10 {
            coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: 0))
        }

        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)

        renderer1 = Renderer1(polyline: polyline, lineWidth: 10)

        renderer2 = Renderer2(polyline: polyline, lineWidth: 10)
    }
}
```

Would someone please help me to understand what is going on here?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me; `MKPolylineRenderer` should be calling `init(overlay:)` on `super` rather than `self`. Because you defined a designated initialiser in `Renderer2`, you don't implicitly inherit the implementation for `init(overlay:)`.

Comment: Although note that the docs for [`MKPolylineRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolylinerenderer) say "*You typically use this class as is and do not subclass it*".

Answer (score 0):

because class initializers are **private**, and you can subclass and init it only by convenience.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline